# Search ignoring all numeric search

Tags: 2013, search, people-search, indexed-column

We are running SharePoint 2013 and are trying to use the people search to find employees by their employee ID number.  The column has been indexed in SharePoint and if we search using the syntax column:123456 the search finds the employee.

Any search that does not use the syntax that explicitly say to use the employee id column to search does not find the employee; for example just searching for 123456 would return no users.

Is there something about all numeric searches that SharePoint is ignoring?

Comment: How is the managed property configured? It might be a problem with how the property is set up

Comment: We are using ADI, this property is mapped to the corresponding attribute in Active Directory.  But I'm not sure if that is what you are asking.

Comment: OK, no I was more concerned about how this User Profile Property is mapped to a Managed Property. Or more precise, how this Managed Property is configured (in the Search Service Application Schema)

Answer (score 1):

Have you set the User Profile Property to "Indexed"?
Have you set the Managed Property to Searchable?

I haven't tested it, but the data type MAY matter. Are you using Text, Integer or Decimal?

Once you get it working you may want to look at using the "Complete Matching" flag on the property, unless you want parial matches to work as well.

Also, If you want to have this be a true alias for the user you should add it to the RankingWeightName managed property and then it will be treated like a username or email address.